# Get the index of first match in the List and add an object before the index using rxjava

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

I have a List of objects in Java, I want to insert an object at index - 1 of the first matched object.
How do that using RXJava? I have read Observable.first() but it only get me the first matched object, no index. Thus, I have no reference of where to insert.

Comment: This isn't 100% clear.  If you're doing `Observable.from(myList)...` then knowing the index would not help you.

Comment: Why are you processing the list with rxJava? It is likely the wrong tool for the job. For that matter, you don't want Java Streams either.

Comment: What do you need as type of the result? A RxJava Observable or a "normal" Java List?